# VSCode - Proper python project with dependencies debugging

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am working on a project in which I use several packages installed on Ubuntu 18.04 using pip3.

My main issue, (which I don't know if it is related to VScode) is that in some cases I need to see how certain packages classe instances are executed by the debugger.

When I debugg the code, the execution is stopped in the break points I put in the .py I created but the ones in the external packages are ignored.

What could be a good workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [`justMyCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019) option into the `launch.json` file

```
"justMyCode": false
```

> When omitted or set to True (the default), restricts debugging to user-written code only. Set to False to also enable debugging of standard library functions.

For example:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```